# Redirect one URL to another using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

My current `.htaccess` file code is as follows:

```
### ISPConfig folder protection begin ###
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Members Only"
AuthUserFile /var/www/web113/web/.htpasswd
require valid-user
### ISPConfig folder protection end ###


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I want to redirect URL as `http://xxxxx.xxxxxx.net/local-attraction` to `http://xxxxx.xxxxx.net/pages/local-attraction`

I have tried with

```
RedirectPermanent http://xxxxx.xxxxxx.net/local-attraction http://xxxxx.xxxxx.net/pages/local-attraction
```

Also with the

```
Redirect 301 /local-attraction http://xxxxx.xxxxx.net/pages/local-attraction
```

But nothing works, it is showing 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mod_rewrite` rule for this redirect since you are already using it your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^local-attraction/?$ /pages/$0 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```